# Tensor product of a ring of integers of a $p$-adic local field and a ring of integers of a number field

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $L$ be a $p$-adic local field and $K$ be a number field. Denote by $O_L$ and $O_K$ the corresponding rings of integers. One has $K=\mathbb Q[x]/(f(x))$ for some $f(x)$. Suppose $f(x)=f_1(x)\cdots f_r(x)$ is the factorization into product of irreducible polynormials in $L[x]$, then
$$L\otimes_{\mathbb Q}K \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r L_i,$$
where $L_i = L[x]/(f_i(x))$.

**Question: (1).** How to describe the factor $L_i$ in a nature way? For example, when $L=\mathbb Q_p$, the direct summand $L_i$ can be described as $\mathfrak p$-adic completion of $K$ for all place $\mathfrak p$ of $K$ above $p$.

**(2).** Do we have
$$O_L \otimes_{\mathbb Z} O_K\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r O_{L_i}\ ?$$